# Simplest standard way to print last bash command with timestamp

Tags: bash, command-history

I would like to print last bash command with its timestamp. `history 1` shows the history command itself. I need to use it on many machines, so it should not depend on any custom configuration. There surely must be some simple command that I am missing to do this, like `lastcmd` or something :)

Note that `fc -l -1` shows the last command but without timestamp, and is too complicated to type it frequently anyway.

Just to clarify, I am looking for some standard and simple way to do this because I need to use it on many servers and it is not feasible to customize them all or create custom functions. Also I need to type this command manually so it should be really simple.

It seems that HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth is a default setting on servers I need to access so I can use:

```
 history 1
```

(history command prefixed with a space) which does not put it in the history, so it correctly shows the last command.

`HISTTIMEFORMAT` is not set by default though, so it is not a complete solution. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Do you mean the timestamp of when the last command *was* run? That is not saved by Bash. It is, however, saved by the Fish shell.

Comment: yes, even just timestamp would be enough for my use case

Comment: could you please specify how to show this timestamp in Fish?

Comment: I don't know exactly an easy way to do it in Fish. I just wrote that it saves that information. However, see here for a script and a feature request: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/677

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that bash does not out of the box provide any simple way to get timestamp when the last command was executed.

In case it is practical for you to customize your servers bash configs you can create custom bash function based on the answer from @terdon.

Answer (score 9):

As you point out, `history 1` prints the `history` command itself since that is the last command you ran. To get the previous one, you'd need `history 2`:

```shellsession
$ touch foo
$ history 2
$ history 2
19950  touch foo
19951  history 2
```

So, to get the previous command without counting `history` itself, pass it through `head -n1`:

```shellsession
$ history 2 | head -n1
19952  touch foo
```

Then, add the time stamp in whatever format you want (see `man 3 strftime` for available formats):

```shellsession
$ HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %H:%M:%S " history 2 | head -n1
19959  2016-06-11 15:06:08 touch foo
```

(You could use also `%T` instead of `%H:%M:%S`)

Comment: thanks this works, but I am still hoping there is something simpler :)

Comment: @mmm it won't get much simpler than `history 2 | head -n1`. You can always set the `HISTTIMEFORMAT` variable in `.profile` or `.bashrc` to avoid setting it in the command. Even simpler, just make the whole thing into an alias.

Comment: I guess this works only while the shell is active, right? Is there a way to configure Bash to store the timestamps with the history?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto it already does, that's why it can print them when told to. Have a look at `~/.bash_history`

Comment: @terdon are you really sure? `tail -n 1 ~/.bash_history` gives me `echo "hello there"`. I am talking about default Bash configuration, since the Q was about "not customizing" the servers.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto sorry it is only written in `~/.bash_history` if the `HISTTIMEFORMAT` variable is set. Try `export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %H:%m:%S"; history -a; tail .bash_history` for example. So, setting `HISTTIMEFORMAT` globally (say in `~/.profile`) should be enough for this to happen automatically.

Comment: @mmm having seen your edit, I see the problem. yes, this would be a pain to type. However, the default behavior is to not show timestamps unless asked for them so I don't think there will be a way around this.

Answer (score 0):

One non-history option that can help is also to customize your shell to show it.
I have it show that and other info (even git branch!) with:

```
HOST='\[\033[02;36m\]\h'; HOST=' '$HOST
TIME='\[\033[01;31m\]\t \[\033[01;32m\]'
LOCATION=' \[\033[01;34m\]`pwd | sed "s#\(/[^/]\{1,\}/[^/]\{1,\}/[^/]\{1,\}/\).*\(/[^/]\{1,\}/[^/]\{1,\}\)/\{0,1\}#\1_\2#g"`'
BRANCH=' \[\033[00;33m\]$(git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\n\$ '
PS1=$TIME$USER$HOST$LOCATION$BRANCH
```

It doesn't help my history per-se but when I scroll back in my terminal at least I can see:

```
$ vi .bashrc
17:57:09 durrantm Castle2012 /home/durrantm 
$ pwd
/home/durrantm
17:57:10 durrantm Castle2012 /home/durrantm 
$ ls *.lt*
ls: cannot access *.lt*: No such file or directory
17:57:15 durrantm Castle2012 /home/durrantm 
$ ls *.rb*
1.rb  2.rb  3.rb  3_step_minimal_foundation_spec.rb  arrival.rb  r.rb  validate_controller.rb  x.rb*
17:57:19 durrantm Castle2012 /home/durrantm 
$ c
17:57:24 durrantm Castle2012 /home/durrantm/Dropbox/_/work/code 
$ which ruby
/home/durrantm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby
17:57:27 durrantm Castle2012 /home/durrantm/Dropbox/_/work/code
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T '
```

and your history file will record times (only for new commands):

```
$ history 5

99576  2016-06-13 02:26:25 export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T '
99580  2016-06-13 02:26:45 bash -c 'IFS=:$IFS ; set -- a b c ; echo "$@ "'
99581  2016-06-13 02:27:37 dash -c 'set a b c; IFS=; echo $*'
99582  2016-06-13 02:28:25 fc -l -1
99607  2016-06-13 02:28:25 history 5
```

## AND

use an space before the command to avoid it being recorded in the history:

```
$  history 1
99607  2016-06-13 02:28:25 history 5
```

---

Then, to make it simpler, make an alias:

```
$ alias h='history 1'
```

Then use it with an space after the `HISTTIMEFORMAT` has been set to get:

```
$  h                ### Understand that there is an space in front of the command.
99607  2016-06-13 02:28:25 history 5
```